# Text won't be shown in IE

Tags: javascript

I have the following problem:

When I click on a button I want a layer to be shown which shows some text. The div layer is under the text. And will be shown like that. But the IEs are not showing any text at all.

The JavaScript is pretty straight forward.

```
document.getElementById("layerUnderText").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("TextOnLayer").style.display = "block";
```

The layer is just a graphic. In CSS the layer has a z-index of 100 and the text of 150. Everything is working fine, except in all versions of IE. Where ist he problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try giving the text layer a

```
position: relative;
```

within the CSS declaration. Often helps in situations like this.